# Modelsim Altera VHDL MEMORY ROM

Tags: vhdl, counter, fsm, rom

I am confused on to why my VHDL design is not working. I am to create a top.vhd file that will program an FPGA board to display addresses 0 through 15 and the corresponding values to each address. When I simulate my design, all the clocks and resets work. The problem I am having is my FSM processes and Address process. I know there is a lot going on here, so if you need clarification I can answer your questions.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity top is

    port(Clock : in std_logic;
          Reset : in std_logic;
          SW    : in  std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);
          HEX2, HEX4: out std_logic_vector ( 6 downto 0);
          KEY0: in std_logic);

end entity;

architecture top_arch of top is

    component char_decoder is
        port(BIN_IN  : in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
          HEX_OUT : out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0));
    end component;

    component rom_16x4_sync is
        port (clock:   in std_logic;
            address: in std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
            rom_en:  in std_logic;
            data_out: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0));
    end component;

    type state_type is (start,  read_rom, clear_addr, done);
    signal current_state, next_state : state_type;
    signal Rom_en, addr_count_clr, addr_count_en : std_logic;
    signal address_counter : integer range 0 to 15;
    signal address_uns : unsigned (3 downto 0);
    signal clock_slow : std_logic;
    signal rom_out : std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

    begin

    char : char_decoder port map (BIN_IN => rom_out, HEX_OUT => HEX2);
    char1 : char_decoder port map (BIN_IN => std_logic_vector(address_uns), HEX_OUT => HEX4);
    clock_slow <= Clock;
    rom : rom_16x4_sync port map (clock => clock_slow, address => std_logic_vector(address_uns), rom_en => Rom_en, data_out => rom_out);



        State_Memory : process (clock_slow, Reset)
            begin
                if (Reset = '0') then
                    current_state <= start;
                elsif (clock_slow'event and clock_slow = '1') then
                            current_state <= next_state;
                end if;
            end process;

        NEXT_STATE_LOGIC : process (current_state)
                begin
                    case (current_state) is
                        when start => if (KEY0 = '0') then
                                            next_state <= read_rom;
                                        else next_state <= start;
                                                                              end if;
                                                when read_rom => if (address_counter = 15) then
                                                next_state <= clear_addr;
                                                else
                                                    address_counter <= address_counter + 1;
                                                end if;
                        when clear_addr => next_state <= done;
                                                 address_counter <= 0;
                        when done => next_state <= done;
                        end case;
                end process;

        OUTPUT_LOGIC : process (current_state)
            begin
                case (current_state) is
                    when start => Rom_en <= '0';
                                            addr_count_en <= '0';
                                            addr_count_clr <= '0';
                    when read_rom => Rom_en <= '1';
                                          addr_count_en <= '1';
                                          addr_count_clr <= '0';
                    when clear_addr => Rom_en <= '0';
                                            addr_count_en <= '1';
                                            addr_count_clr <= '1';
                    when done => Rom_en <= '0';
                                            addr_count_en <= '0';
                                            addr_count_clr <= '0';
                    end case;
            end process;



            Address_Count : process (addr_count_en, addr_count_clr, clock_slow)
                begin
                if (clock_slow'event and clock_slow = '1') then
                    if (addr_count_en = '1') then
                        if (addr_count_clr = '1') then
                            address_uns <= "0000";
                        else
                            address_uns <= address_uns + 1;
                        end if;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end process;
              address_uns <= to_unsigned(address_counter,4);



end architecture;
```

Comment: Please also post your testbench. What is the specific problem you encounter? I suspect, your clock is just too fast to distinguish the hexadecimal output.

Comment: Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), since that will greatly help to make a useful answer, and you are in that process even likely to find an answer yourself.

Comment: [Some questions are still off-topic...](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) 1. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Without a clear problem statement or an mcve only possible to comment. `address_counter` isn't clocked and is redundant. Remove the assignments and change the comparison to `address_uns` (which should also go into the sensitity list) in process `NEXT_STATE_LOGIC`.  Remove the concurrent signal assignment to `address_uns` following process `Address_Counter`. If processes `Address_Count` and `OUTPUT_LOGIC` are correct as well as `rom_16x4_sync` you should have something that works. (And without an mcve a second party can't determine that).

Answer (score 0):

I commented on what I could see wrong with your code:

`address_counter` isn't clocked and is redundant. Remove the assignments and change the comparison to `address_uns` (which should also go into the sensitivity list) in process `NEXT_STATE_LOGIC`. Remove the concurrent signal assignment to address_uns following process `Address_Counter`. If processes `Address_Count` and `OUTPUT_LOGIC` are correct as well as rom_16x4_sync you should have something that works.

Well I had most the bits and pieces sitting around from other questions to gen a complete MCVE together with little effort mostly by copying and pasting and that gave:

[image: top_tb.png]

As you can see that didn't work, and the reason why is that `address_uns` needs to be reset (it's default value is all 'U's).

Adding a reset gives:

[image: top_tb_address_us_reset]

So the gist of this is that your state machine was almost correct, it was missing the address counter in it's sensitivity list and had two address counters. Limiting that to one and resetting it so you weren't adding 1 to all 'U's shows your state machine is working.

And the code with all the fixes:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity char_decoder is
    port (
        bin_in:   in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        hex_out:  out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture dummy of char_decoder is
    --  seven segment display
    --  
    --        a
    --     f      b
    --        g
    --     e      c
    --        d
    --
    --  SEGMENT is defined (g downto a)
    --
    type segment7 is array (integer range 0 to 15) of 
                                std_logic_vector (6 downto 0);

    constant hex_to_segment: segment7 := (
                 "1000000", -- 0
                 "1111001", -- 1
                 "0100100", -- 2
                 "0110000", -- 3
                 "0011001", -- 4
                 "0010010", -- 5
                 "0000010", -- 6
                 "1111000", -- 7
                 "0000000", -- 8
                 "0011000", -- 9
                 "0001000", -- A
                 "0000011", -- b
                 "0111001", -- C
                 "0100001", -- d
                 "0000110", -- E
                 "0001110"  -- F
             );
begin
    process (bin_in)
        variable seg7_val: integer range 0 to 15;
    begin
        seg7_val := to_integer(unsigned(bin_in));

        hex_out <= hex_to_segment(seg7_val);
    end process;
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity rom_16x4_sync is
    port (
        clock:    in  std_logic;
        address:  in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
        rom_en:   in  std_logic;
        data_out: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
    );
end entity;

architecture dummy of rom_16x4_sync is
    type rom_array is array (0 to 15) of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);

    function fill_rom return rom_array is 
        variable ret_val:   rom_array;
    begin
        for i in rom_array'reverse_range loop  -- backward to i
            ret_val(i) := std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(i,4)); 
        end loop;
        return ret_val;
    end function;
    constant rom:   rom_array := fill_rom;
begin
    process (clock)
    begin
        if rising_edge(clock) and rom_en = '1' then  -- NO RESET
            data_out <= rom(to_integer(unsigned(address)));
        end if;
    end process;
end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity top is
    port (
        clock:      in  std_logic;
        reset:      in  std_logic;
        sw:         in  std_logic_vector (1 downto 0);  -- not used?
        hex2, hex4: out std_logic_vector ( 6 downto 0);
        key0:       in  std_logic
    );
end entity;

architecture top_arch of top is

    component char_decoder is
        port (
            bin_in:   in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
            hex_out:  out std_logic_vector (6 downto 0)
        );
    end component;

    component rom_16x4_sync is
        port (
            clock:    in  std_logic;
            address:  in  std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
            rom_en:   in  std_logic;
            data_out: out std_logic_vector(3 downto 0)
        );
    end component;

    type state_type is (start,  read_rom, clear_addr, done);
    signal current_state, 
           next_state:          state_type;
    signal rom_en, 
           addr_count_clr, 
           addr_count_en:       std_logic;
    -- signal address_counter:     integer range 0 to 15;
    signal address_uns:         unsigned (3 downto 0);
    signal clock_slow:          std_logic;
    signal rom_out:             std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

    begin

char:  
    char_decoder 
        port map (
            bin_in => rom_out, 
            hex_out => hex2
        );
char1:  
    char_decoder 
        port map (
            bin_in => std_logic_vector(address_uns), 
            hex_out => hex4
        );

    clock_slow <= clock;

rom:  
    rom_16x4_sync 
        port map (
            clock => clock_slow, 
            address => std_logic_vector(address_uns), 
            rom_en => rom_en, data_out => rom_out
        );

state_memory:  
    process (clock_slow, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '0' then
            current_state <= start;
        elsif clock_slow'event and clock_slow = '1' then
            current_state <= next_state;
        end if;
    end process;

next_state_logic:  
    -- process (current_state)
    process (current_state, address_uns)
    begin
        case (current_state) is
            when start => 
                if key0 = '0' then
                    next_state <= read_rom;
                else 
                    next_state <= start;
                end if;
            when read_rom => 
                if address_uns = 15 then
                    next_state <= clear_addr;
                -- else
                --    address_counter <= address_counter + 1;
                end if;
            when clear_addr =>   -- not a defined sequential logic inference
                next_state <= done;
                -- address_counter <= 0;
            when done => 
                next_state <= done;
        end case;
    end process;

output_logic:  
    process (current_state)
        begin
            case (current_state) is
                when start => 
                    rom_en <= '0';
                    addr_count_en <= '0';
                    addr_count_clr <= '0';
                when read_rom => 
                    rom_en <= '1';
                    addr_count_en <= '1';
                    addr_count_clr <= '0';
                when clear_addr => 
                    rom_en <= '0';
                    addr_count_en <= '1';
                    addr_count_clr <= '1';
                when done => 
                    rom_en <= '0';
                    addr_count_en <= '0';
                    addr_count_clr <= '0';
                end case;
        end process;

address_count:  
    process (addr_count_en, addr_count_clr, clock_slow)
    begin
        if reset = '0' then                   -- added reset
            address_uns <= (others =>'0');
        elsif clock_slow'event and clock_slow = '1' then
            if addr_count_en = '1' then
                if addr_count_clr = '1' then
                    address_uns <= "0000";
                else
                    address_uns <= address_uns + 1;
                end if;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    -- address_uns <= to_unsigned(address_counter, 4);

end architecture;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity top_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of top_tb is
    signal clock:      std_logic := '0';
    signal reset:      std_logic := '1';
    signal sw:         std_logic_vector (1 downto 0) := "00";
    signal hex2, hex4: std_logic_vector ( 6 downto 0);
    signal key0:       std_logic := '0';
begin
DUT:
    entity work.top
        port map (
            clock => clock,
            reset => reset,
            sw => sw,
            hex2 => hex2,
            hex4 => hex4,
            key0 => key0
        );
CLK:
    process
    begin
        wait for 5 ns;    
        clock <= not clock;
        if now > 200 ns then
            wait;
        end if;    
    end process;

STIMULIS:
    process
    begin
        wait for 1 ns;
        reset <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        reset <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

The `char_decoder` I used should be fully functional. The ROM contents are simply dummied up.